# Trignometric Substitution Problem. Can't find right answer

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve an integral that involves using Trig Sub (I know it can be also done with partial fraction).

However, no matter how many times I try, I still cannot find the right answer. I hope someone can point out where I did wrong :)

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} dx$

- $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{1-x^{2}})^{2}} d x$
- $\displaystyle x = \sin\theta, dx=\cos\theta \, d\theta, \sqrt{1-x^{2}} =\cos\theta$
- $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(\cos \theta)^{2}} \cos \theta \, d \theta$
- $\displaystyle \int \sec \theta \, d \theta$
- $\displaystyle \ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|+ C$
- $\displaystyle \ln \left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right|+C$

I hope someone can tell me where I commit an error Thanks!

Comment: This isnt trig sub, it is a standard integral of artanh(x)

Comment: @jamie But many standard integrals can be proved without differentiation by using a trig substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. You just need to simplify the answer a bit.
$$\ln \Big(\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Big)=\ln \Big(\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}}\Big)=\ln \Big(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\Big)=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\Big(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)  $$

Comment: $\ln\Big(\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}}\Big)=\ln \Big({\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)}^\frac{1}{2}$. Now I can simply take the power down by multiplying it with $\ln$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes yes I just realized.

Comment: ln(y)^n = n ln(y). In your case y becomes (1+x/1-x) & n is the value of square root i.e. 1/2.

Comment: Yes yes. It is the problem with the website I am using. I wrote this answer, they say it was incorrect. That is why I calculated at least 10 times :( Thanks for saving me haha

Answer (score 2):

Write
$1/(1-x^2)
= (1/2)(1/(1-x)+1/(1+x))
$.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how did you get this? Because I suppose to use Trig Sub for this question.

Comment: As the other answer showed, you just didn't take it far enough. However, I think that whenever a denominator can be factored, a partial fraction decomposition should be done because the terms will be simpler.